# Ryu SDN Controller - How to get specific information regarding the flowing packets

Tags: python, sdn, ryu

I'm trying to learn the Ryu SDN Controller for a personal project, and i need to know certain packet information to decide what to do with it.

I've already imported :

```
from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet
from ryu.lib.packet import packet
from ryu.lib.packet import arp
from ryu.lib.packet import ipv4
from ryu.lib.packet import tcp
from ryu.lib.packet import tcp
```

And with the above modules i've made a sequence of prints to check de full packet especifications:

```
msg = ev.msg
datapath = msg.datapath
ofproto = datapath.ofproto
parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
in_port = msg.match['in_port']

pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]
arp_pkt = pkt.get_protocol(arp.arp)
ipv4_pkt = pkt.get_protocol(ipv4.ipv4)
tcp_pkt = pkt.get_protocol(tcp.tcp)
udp_pkt = pkt.get_protocol(udp.udp)

print("\nEth pkt: {0}".format(eth))
print("\nIPV4 pkt: {0}".format(ipv4_pkt))
print("\nARP pkt: {0}".format(arp_pkt))
print("\nTCP pkt: {0}".format(tcp_pkt))
print("\nUDP pkt: {0}".format(udp_pkt))
```

and when i try to estabilish a TCP connection i receive the following prints:

```
Eth pkt: ethernet(dst='00:00:00:00:00:02',ethertype=2048,src='00:00:00:00:00:01')

IPV4 pkt: ipv4(csum=32564,dst='10.0.0.2',flags=2,header_length=5,identification=42869,offset=0,option=None,proto=6,src='10.0.0.1',tos=16,total_length=60,ttl=64,version=4)

ARP pkt: None

TCP pkt: tcp(ack=0,bits=2,csum=6900,dst_port=5001,offset=10,option='\x02\x04\x05\xb4\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\x10\xf05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\t',seq=1729779520,src_port=58573,urgent=0,window_size=29200)

UDP pkt: None
packet in 1 00:00:00:00:00:01 00:00:00:00:00:02 1
```

my question is: how do i for instance retrive de destination port from insde tcp_pkt :

```
tcp_pkt = tcp(ack=0,bits=2,csum=6900,dst_port=5001,offset=10,option='\x02\x04\x05\xb4\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\x10\xf05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\t',seq=1729779520,src_port=58573,urgent=0,window_size=29200)
```

is there something like tcp_pkt.dst()? Or is there a another way to catch that value?

Answer (score 0):

The Ryu repository is on GitHub and can be found [here](https://github.com/osrg/ryu).

If you take a look at the `packet` module, you'll find a file called **[tcp.py](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/lib/packet/tcp.py)**.

For extracting the destination port from a given network packet, you need to access the *transport layer header*. In this case it is TCP, so from the file (tcp.py) that I included above you can see that there is a variable called `dst_port`.

Therefore, in your code you should include:

```
from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet, packet, arp, ipv4, tcp, udp

msg = ev.msg
datapath = msg.datapath
ofproto = datapath.ofproto
parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
in_port = msg.match['in_port']

pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]
arp_pkt = pkt.get_protocol(arp.arp)
ipv4_pkt = pkt.get_protocol(ipv4.ipv4)
#fetches 3rd item from list of protocols (tcp or udp). Instead of having separate udp and tcp
layer4_header = pkt.protocols[2]
#Now to extract the destination port
destination_port = layer4_header.dst_port
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP Source port and Destination ports can be retrieved just like you retrieve ethernet source and destination MAC addresses. However, you have to put a small check in order to make sure if there is TCP traffic:

```
if pkt.get_protocols(tcp.tcp):
    print(pkt.get_protocols(tcp.tcp)[0].dst_port)
```